# Has anyone confirmed Egypt's [cover?] story that they are building a walled "logistical hub" (and not a displacement camp) next to Gaza?

Tags: borders, 2023-israel-hamas-war, egypt, humanitarian-aid

There have been press reports (e.g. [latest](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-68375460)) that Egypt is clearing up and walling (with concrete slabs, about 5m tall judging from the pictures) an area of about 16 sq km next to their current border fence with Gaza.

> Sections of wall around this area now appear to be under construction.
>
> On 14 February, about 0.8km (0.5 miles) of wall were visible in satellite imagery, but the most recent pictures indicate more than 4km (2.5 miles) are now erected.

The official story from Egypt seems to be that it's a "logistical hub". However,

> But an aid worker for a UK charity, who is part of the humanitarian efforts in Gaza, told the BBC she had "never seen large scale clearing of land" for such a logistical hub and they were unaware of any such plan. [...]
>
> "If there was a plan to suddenly increase the capacity by constructing a hub of sorts, I would suggest that this would have been shared [with aid agencies] by the Egyptian authorities," she said.
>
> The aid worker didn't want to be named, as it could complicate the relationship between the aid organisation she works for and the Egyptian authorities.

So, has anyone besides Egypt (e.g. USA, Israel, etc.) confirmed that this is indeed more likely to be a logistical hub as claimed by Egypt? (Previous aid-related developments involved a complicated and often public dance between the US, Israel, and Egypt, with announcements from more than one party/side, [e.g.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlJy_ZxsM3s), [e.g.2](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/gaza-israel-kerem-shalom-white-house-biden-rcna130864). So, it seems a bit mysterious that Egypt would embark on such a large-scale project without its partners in aid saying something.)

Comment: Even CGTN's [coverage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9K8ajL0B7M), while saying the official line first, adds something about the "speculation" that it could be used for refugees. The 5m wall is apparently to protect the zone from "inclement weather", said the Egyptian governor.

Comment: I didn't downvote but it could be argued that it's asked in bad faith to make a point, on the basis that nobody seriously believes it's a logistics hub, and isn't likely to elicit any answer. If you actually wanted to know the purpose of the site and if it has other possible uses than as a concentration camp, there would be better ways to get a factual answer.

Comment: @StuartF: I'm honestly not sure. Netanyahu recently [announced](https://edition.cnn.com/2024/02/23/middleeast/netanyahu-unveils-future-post-hamas-gaza-plan-mime-intl/index.html) they plan to completely close the Gaza border crossing with Egypt, but it's not clear how/if the Egyptian construction is related. In fact, he said even [earlier on Jan 13](https://edition.cnn.com/2024/01/13/world/philadelphi-corridor-israel-gaza-netanyahu/index.html).